# How to add -std=c++0x into the eclipse ubuntu?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, ubuntu

I am trying to add `-std=c++0x` into the eclipse Ubuntu but I do not know how to add it.

My original set up:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/copy2.d" -MT"src/copy2.d" -o "src/copy2.o" "../src/copy2.cpp"
```

Does not include `-std=c++0x` that's why giving me the error when I run `std::stoi`:

> error: `stoi` is not a member of `std`

My expectation:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 MMD -MP -MF"src/copy2.d" -MT"src/copy2.d" -o "src/copy2.o" "../src/copy2.cpp"
```

Comment: You are missing a '-' before MMD

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: version 3.8 and It's been working with this option but I do not remember how to add -std=c++0x into it. By instruction, we need to go into the property of the project --> C/C++ Build --> Setting --> add on the command box "gcc;-std=c++0x"
I did not know I added right or wrong? or somewhere else?

Comment: @NateDuong You need to add that option in the _C/C++->Build Settings_ for the c++ compiler, not the c compiler.

Comment: `gcc` looks wrong, since this is for `g++`